# Unable to change screen resolution on Ubuntu 16.04 installed on asus ux305fa

Tags: asus, display-resolution, xrandr

I've installed ubuntu 16.04 on my asus ux305fa but the screen resolution is set at 96x96 DPI, which make everything look very small. I know that the optimal resolution would be 138x138 but when I try to change it from terminal nothing happens. I've tried with xrandr:

```
`xrandr -- dpi 138/eDP1`
```

and

```
 `xrandr -s 1920x1080`
```

It seems like the xrandr command doesn't work at all